# How to hide vertical border in editor

Tags: android-studio

How to hide vertical border in editor (or change it position)?

It affects the code placement.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest IntelliJ it's at:

"Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show hard wrap and visual guides (configured in Code Style options)"

But the visible line is more "informational" if you don't like the way the IDE formats your code, you should configure that in;

"Settings > Editor > Code Style"